# Express Js + Node JS + load .html into div and change URI

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, url-routing, ejs

I recently started to use Express.js alongside with Node.js and rendering engine .ejs

I would like to load an .ejs file, which is basically a form of .html into a div on my page. I am so far quite acquainted with how to do it using jQuery s' load() function, but the URI after using this method remains the same. like in the example below:

```
$('.about').bind('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.container').load('about.ejs');
})
```

I click the about button, and it loads about into div. But the URI remains the same www.page.com/

The way I have it working in Node.JS and Express.JS is as follows:

```
app.get('/about', function (req, res){
    res.render('about',{
        title: appName,
        menu:  "about" 
    });
});
```

Is there any way I can recreate this behavior using Express js so that it changes the URI to mypage.com/about  ?

Comment: um... maybe just a regular hyperlink? .ejs supports things like layouts and partials, so there you go.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the page to reload, just the particular div to be populated with loaded html. Kind of like when you click a link on Facebook and your chat window remains in place whilst the page I is being loaded with new data.

Comment: Then you should look into AJAX.

Comment: What is the purpose of having such powerful framework like node.js and not being able to preform such a basic task ?

Comment: because it is a client-side issue, not a server-side issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('.about').bind('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.container').load('about.ejs');
    history.pushState({}, 'About', '/about');
});
```

Be careful though. [Not all browsers support push state.](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate) There are libraries, like [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax), that handle this for you.

Comment: Thank You. It helped. What can I say.